# Не запускается jar файл (Error)

Tags: jar

При попытке запустить jar файл в cmd выдает:

```
C:\Java\Projects>java -jar C:\Java\Projects\Test.jar
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0
```

Версия

```
C:\Java\Projects>java --version
java 16.0.2 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чётко же написано: у Вас старая версия джавы, а файл скомпилирован под новую.

Comment: в Intellij вроде компилировал в 17, но не в винде не пойму, где Установлена новая версия, чтобы прописать ее в PATH

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт!
Скачать 17 версию заново!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).